# Cryogenic engines till date

Tags: cryogenics, turbopump

How many cryogenic engines are there till date.

Names are mostly necessary.

Comment: What is your definition of a cryogenic engine? An engine using the cryogenic oxidator LOX only or an engine using cryogenic LOX and a fuel like liquid hydrogen or methane?

Comment: Basically using LOX and any fuel like RP-1, LH2 etc

Comment: If LOX engines are included, the list is going to be huge. Why do you want to know? There's a list of orbital-launcher engines on Wikipedia, and you can see which ones use LOX or cryo fuels, but it's not complete. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_rocket_engines

Comment: I mostly want cryogenic engines list. Actually i'll brought it down to lox/lh2 and lox/RP-1 only.